# enabling the tls/ssl in windows 10

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php, tls1.2

For some reason I was unable to install a project from github. So I had to disable ssl/tls to run this command:

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

Now I am unable to enable tls.

how can I enable it again? Because it is disabled I am not able to update.
[image]

Running composer self-update command gives this warning and I am unable to update composer to latest version composer.

Comment: Based on the error you're showing it seems to be telling you to do what you say you already did...which is to set the disable-tls option to true if you want to hide the error.  Have you checked your php.ini to see if php_openssl is enabled?